# Why does time difference measurement with `std::chrono` give more significant digits with `float` type, compared to `double` type?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, double, c++-chrono

I measured several time differences by using `std::chrono` tools. I did my test with both float and double types. There was something surprising in the results; the double type goes to `...0000000` or `...9999999` after 7<sup>th</sup> digit, while the float type goes on displaying significant digits.

The code:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point Start, End;
std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1>> fDuration;
std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, 1>> dbDuration;
std::cout.precision(20);
std::cout << std::fixed;
for (DWORD dwSleepTime=0; dwSleepTime<=10000; dwSleepTime+=1000)
{
    Start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Sleep(dwSleepTime);
    End = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    fDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(End - Start);
    dbDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(End - Start);
    std::cout << "Time passed (float)  = " << fDuration.count()  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time passed (double) = " << dbDuration.count() << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Its output:

```
Time passed (float)  = 0.00000000000000000000
Time passed (double) = 0.00000000000000000000

Time passed (float)  = 1.00005722045898440000
Time passed (double) = 1.00005720000000010000

Time passed (float)  = 2.00011444091796870000
Time passed (double) = 2.00011440000000020000

Time passed (float)  = 3.00017166137695310000
Time passed (double) = 3.00017159999999980000

Time passed (float)  = 4.00022888183593750000
Time passed (double) = 4.00022880000000040000

Time passed (float)  = 5.00028610229492190000
Time passed (double) = 5.00028600000000000000

Time passed (float)  = 6.00034332275390620000
Time passed (double) = 6.00034319999999970000

Time passed (float)  = 7.00040006637573240000
Time passed (double) = 7.00040040000000020000

Time passed (float)  = 8.00045776367187500000
Time passed (double) = 8.00045760000000070000

Time passed (float)  = 9.00051498413085940000
Time passed (double) = 9.00051479999999950000

Time passed (float)  = 10.00057220458984400000
Time passed (double) = 10.00057200000000000000
```

What is the reason behind this phenomenon? Is the double type really giving less precise results in this particular case?

---

My system:
IDE: Visiual Studio 2012
OS: Windows 7 x64
CPU: Intel i5 750

Comment: It's a binary format. Don't look at its decimal form to judge precision...

Comment: Did you ask yourself, how many significant digits `float` has after the decimal point?

Comment: The fact that a conversion from binary to decimal can *produce* non-zero digits doesn't make those digits truly significant.

Comment: You are using `std::chrono`. Why you don't use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` instead of a Win32 API system-depenent function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `double` type represents values precisely. So, when you print them, you see a value that is very close to the original value. E.g., when the original value is 1.0000572, and it is converted to `double`, the result is 1.000057200000000090511775852064602077007293701171875, because that is the closest value that `double` can represent.

The `float` type represents values less precisely. When you convert 1.0000572, the result is 1.000057220458984375, because that is a close as `float` can get to 1.0000572.

Additionally, when you convert these to decimal for printing with Visual Studio software, only the first 17 digits are displayed, because Visual Studio stops there and prints the remaining digits as zero. (It should be clear that the fact that they are printed this way does not mean the `float` and `double` objects have these values. The IEEE-754 floating-point standard makes it clear that the exact values represented are the ones I have shown above, 1.000057220458984375 and 1.000057200000000090511775852064602077007293701171875. High-quality software prints the exact values to as many decimal digits as requested.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to read up about binary floating points and precision! `float` has 6 decimal digits of precision, `double` has 16 decimal digits of precision (I think but I keep misremembering the exact values; check `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10`). Since binary floating points can't representation fractional decimal values exactly (only some but many not), printing the binary floating point values causes some rounding when leaving the printing routine to do what it wants to do. When you ask for more than `digits10` digits, the rounding will generally be put off and it prints the actual binary fractional value up to whatever number of digits you asked for.

In the case you described above the `float` version just starts printing the actual values (which can have up to `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` significant places). The `double` version seems to still round reasonably although asking for 20 digits already puts it into the area where the values from the approximation should/could/might be shown. Of course, none of that has anything to do with `std::chrono` but is merely about binary floating points.